# Two dimensional array android - implement and add values - Android Java

Tags: android, arrays

I am not sure if I should use two dimensional array or something different. I have a word, for example `apple` , and I have two definitions for this word - ex. `I like eating the apple` and `An apple is red`.

And I want to display this word either with first sentence or second sentence.

Simply, I want to link this word with two definitions and display it easily. How can I do that?

Comment: 2D array sounds like it should work. You can always find alternatives, of course (such as `Map<String, List<String>>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Sentence" />
```

In JAVA:

```
private View view;
     private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> words;
            private Boolean isClicked = false;
    @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
            initView();
            return view;
        }

        private void initView() {
    final Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    words = new HashMap<>();
            final ArrayList<String> appleDefs = new ArrayList<>();

            appleDefs.add("def one");
            appleDefs.add("def two");

            words.put("Apple", appleDefs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
     case R.id.button1:
                    clickCheck();
                    break;
    }
    }
 private void clickCheck() {
        if (isClicked) {
            if (words.get("Apple").size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, words.get("Apple").get(1));
            }
            isClicked = false;

        } else {
            if (words.get("Apple").size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, words.get("Apple").get(0));
            }
            isClicked = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was really usefull! Thank you friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map of Lists, its easier to navigate, e.g. `Map<String, List<String>> words = new HashMap<>();`

Usage:

```
List<String> appleDefs = new ArrayList<>();

appleDefs.add("def one");
appleDefs.add("def two");

words.put("Apple", appleDefs);
```

Comment: It seems to be good. How can I get values from this map of lists?? For ex. if i click button, i get first definition, and if I click button again, I get second definition?

Comment: Well, one approach would be to `remove(index)`the displayed definition from the `List` instead of simply `get(index)`-ing it. Or add the displayed definitions to another arbitrary list and before displaying, make sure the current one to be displayed is not in the `displayed` collection. There are infinite ways to go about that, just pick one and run

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I think I got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only ever going to have 2 sentences you could create a class to store the info e.g

```
public class WordObj {
    private String word;
    private String sentence1, sentence2;


    public WordObj(String word, String definition1, String definition2) {
        this.word = word;
        this.sentence1 = definition1;
        this.sentence2 = definition2;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public String getSentence1() {
        return sentence1;
    }

    public String getSentence2() {
        return sentence2;
    }

}
```

Then use it like:

```
ArrayList<WordObj> words = new ArrayList<>();

words.add(new WordObj("Apple", "I like eating the apple", "An apple is red"));
```

EDIT:
For a variable amount of sentences:

```
public class WordObj {
    private String word;
    private ArrayList<String> sentences;

    public WordObj(String word, ArrayList<String> sentences) {
        this.word = word;
        this.sentences = sentences;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSentences() {
        return sentences;
    }

    public String getSentence(int position) {
        return sentences.get(position);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ArrayList<WordObj> words = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<String> appleSentences = new ArrayList<>();
appleSentences.add("I like eating the apple");
appleSentences.add("An apple is red");

words.add(new WordObj("Apple", appleSentences));
```

Comment: I sometimes have more than 2 sentences. Thank you for your answer tho.